# Реализация в NodeJS MongoDB native driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, node-modules

После перебирания Гоголевских ответов и Ютубовских видео, так и не нашел решения моего вопроса....

Нужно реализовать следующую функцию, используя node.js mongodb native driver:

```
var users =[{name:"one",warns:1}]; //Можно сказать, что это db.collection("users").find().toArray(callback);
function plus(name){ //Та самая функция
    for(i in users){ //Перебираем йузеров, да бы найти нужного (Вроде, можно использовать db.collection("users").findOne({name:name},callback)")
        if(users[i].name === name) { //Если находим
            users[i].warns++; //Прибавляем 1 к параметру warns
            return; //И сваливаем
        }
    }//Иначе, если таковой не нашелся - создаём его
    users.push({name:name, warns:1});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с нативным драйвером использовать промисы, а следовательно и `async/await`. Если я правильно понял то можно написать так

```js
function add(name){
        (async () => {
            try {
                let collection = db.collection('users');
                let user = await collection.findOne({ name: name });
                if (user) {
                    user.warns++;
                    await collection.updateOne({ name: name }, user);
                } else {
                    await collection.insertOne({name: name, warns:1});
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        });
}
```

Через колбеки

```js
function add(name){
        db.collection('users').findOne({ name: name }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (user) {
                user.warns++;
                db.collection('users').updateOne({ name: name }, user, (err, result) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);
                });
            } else {
     

       db.collection('users').insertOne({ name: name, warns: 1 }, (err, result) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Общий смысл понял, но код не рабочий...
После findOne(...) тишина

Comment: Попробуйте пошагать. Возможно не нашло в базе документ.

Comment: Сейчас вожусь с отладчиком... Смысл в том, что при не нахождении документа, он должен создаваться....

Comment: та и есть. Через пол часа запущу код у себя попробую что там

Comment: Кажись мой косяк в вот, что я передаю в качестве name...
Копаю дальше....